# How to Change ToolTip Color

Tags: xaml, tooltip

How i can change ToolTip Color In My Code

```
    <Style x:Key="textBoxInError" TargetType="TextBox">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create your own tool tip style [See Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745107%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Note that the Style should have to be defult 
`<Style TargetType="ToolTip"> ... </Style>`

to have it apply "textBoxInError" Style.